# How to prove by induction that a parabola corresponding to two edges intersects at atmost 2 points?

Tags: algorithm, math, theory, proof

I have many parabolas that are intersecting each other. I am generating a list *S* from the upper segments of these parabolas. Since the corresponding two edges of a parabola intersect each other at most at 2 points, the list *S* can contain at most *2n – 1* items.

I want to prove this by induction. What I can think of is this:

Assume I have *f(x) ≤ 2n – 1*.

Base case is *n = 1, f(1) ≤ 2 · 1 – 1*, so *f(1) <= 1*.

Then assume *n = k* holds, so *f(k) ≤ 2k – 1*.

We can show that for *n = k+1* holds *f(k+1) ≤ 2(k+1) – 1*.

Am I supposed to continue like that, e.g. for *n = k+2*, *n = k+3*, …? If I continue like this, then does it mean I proved it by induction?

Comment: No, once you prove the base case and that if it is true for k, it is also true for k+1 you are done. since you just proved it is true for k+1, for k'=k+1, it will also be true for k'+1=k+2 and so on..

Comment: why i am confused is, i didn't do anything to prove it. i only put an input to the function (e.g. k+1) and that's all. is this a proof? i feel like i should do something more.

Comment: I see what you are asking now. You didn't really prove the claim for k+1. I'll add an answer describing a full prove.

Comment: This is more math than algorithmic oriented. I'm not closing it, but you might find math.stackexchange.com useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

claim: `f(n) <= 2n-1`

base: for n=1, there are no intersections at all [a parabola cannot intersect with itself, so there is only one segment and: `f(1)=1<=2-1=1`, so the claim for n=1 is true.

We will show that if the claim is true for an arbitrary k, it is also true for k+1.

`f(k+1)<=f(k)+2` because there are additional 2 segments, at most, and therefore :

`f(k+1)<=f(k)+2<=(*)2k-1+2=2k+1<=2(k+1)-1`

(*)from the induction assumption

From the induction, the claim is true for each k>=1.

If i understood correctly what you are trying to prove, this proof should cover it.

Comment: now i get it. many thanks. one thing: what (*) means in the 6th line?

Comment: @Noopur: (*)from the induction assumption, I forgot to add it, added it now. :)